# Incremental load for Updates into Warehouse

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, data-warehouse

I am planning for an incremental load into warehouse (especially for updates of source tables in RDBMS).

Capturing the updated rows in staging tables from RDBMS based the updates datetime. But how do I determine which column of a particular row needs to be updated in the target warehouse tables?

Or do I just delete a particular row in the warehouse table (based on the primary key of the row in staging table) and insert the new updated row?

Which is the best way to implement the incremental load between the RDBMS and Warehouse using PL/SQL and SQL coding?

Comment: too broad question... look into documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/transform.htm

Comment: here are some methods described: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84163/2047

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to accomplish this is as follows:

1. Create a stage table identical to your host table.  When you do your incremental/net-change load, load all changed records into this table (based on whatever your "last updated" field is)
2. Delete the records from your actual table based on the primary key.  For example, if your primary key is customer, part, the query might look like this:

   `delete from main_table m
   where exists (
     select null
     from stage_table s
     where
       m.customer = s.customer and
       m.part = s.part
   );`
3. Insert the records from the stage to the main table.

You could also do an update existing records / insert new records, but either way that's two steps.  The advantage of the method I listed is that it will work even if your tables have partitions and the newly updated data violates one of the original partition rules, whereas an update would not accomplish that.  Also, the syntax is much simpler as your update would have to list every single field, whereas the `delete from` / `insert into` allows you list only the primary key fields.

Oracle also has a `merge` clause that will update if it exists or insert if it does not.  I honestly don't know how that would be impacted if you had partitions.

One major caveat.  If your updates include deletes -- records that need to be deleted from the main table, none of these will resolve that and you will need some other way to handle that.  It may not be necessary, depending on your circumstances, but it's something to consider.